# Placeholder in "replaceAll"

Tags: java, string

I have a String like `"§aTest§5This§rIs§tA§2Test"`. I want to use `replaceAll` to replace every instance of `§x`, with `x`, where `x` means any character.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: You wrote the answer in your title :| `replaceAll("§(.)", "$1");`

Comment: Ah, that "(.)" was the part I didn't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String stringCleanup(final String aString) {
    return aString.replaceAll("§(.)", "$1");
}
```

You can even generalize the above answer to accept an argument with the characters you want to remove.